# Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a global array:

```
let genderList = ["Not Selected", "Woman", "Man", "Non Binary", "Trans", "Would rather not say"]
```

A struct instance variable:

```
@State var selectedGender = genderList[0]
```

And a picker in my View:

```
Picker("Please select your gender", selection: $selectedGender) {
    ForEach(genderList, id: \.self) {
        Text($0)
        }
}.pickerStyle(.wheel)
```

For the life of me I can't seem to understand why this throws the following error:

> Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range

I tried this as well with similar error:

```
Picker("", selection: $selectedGender) {
    ForEach(genderList.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        Text(genderList[index])
    }
}.pickerStyle(.wheel)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Did you try to print the indexes in the loop ?

Comment: It means that the index it's trying to access is past the array count itself (i.e. out of range). Try something like "ForEach(0..<genderList.count ...".

Comment: @Echizzle `genderList.indices` is the correct way to get the indices of an array. `0..<a.count` doesn't work correctly for array slices and things with non-integer indices)

Comment: `indices` and ranges are unsafe with SwiftUI for this reason. You should watch Demystify SwiftUI

Comment: When does the crash happen, on selection or when the view appears?

@Alexander true, and it looks like the code in question should work properly.

Comment: Both variants of the code work for me in a playground on my iPad.

Comment: You say the array is global, do you have any local property/variable with the same name perhaps? A reproducible example would be very helpful.

Comment: I would suggest to test replace the State var selectedGender = genderList[0] (accessing the index in the Sate initialisation) with State var selectedGender = "Not Selected" if that works its a race condition issue as suggested previously. For me I have only seen these issues in apps with complex view hierarchies . Testing in a simple single view your codes works fine for me with a global var.

Comment: I think most likely it's something related to threads: for example are you sure `let genderList = ["Not Selected", "Woman", "Man", "Non Binary", "Trans", "Would rather not say"]` is always initialized on main thread? If it's not, maybe you have a race condition between `selectedGender` and `genderList` initialization. And in any case, we are missing some info here: when it crashes, follow the trace and confirm that you pinpointed the place correctly...

Comment: It's to do with setting the state to [0] of an array that might not be available yet in a race condition of application start up. See the updated test code in my updated answer below. Set the values either directly on the state at initialisation in the view or somewhere else in the app as a dependency, not as global var.

Comment: This works fine if I isolate the view and only have that one view showing. The crash happens the moment a button is pressed to navigate to the next view after selecting the gender.

Comment: ```
Picker("Please select your gender", selection: $selectedGender) {
                    ForEach(genderList, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                
                Text("You selected: \(selectedGender)")
```

While in the view, the Text View after the picker works just fine. 
The fault occurs at @main when loading the nextView believe

Comment: In swiftui you should have all you application need data stored within a view and passed around. The moment you are using global vars and then unsafe index access you are going to have problems. Why is the value not a class singleton, observable object or a state/binding var passed between view? Also if it must be the case you need to have an initialiser and check of array.isEmpty rather than just accessing [0]. Forget all the long answers and time I wasted testing this, if you acces

Comment: I have a similar issue. The crash happens on `@main` of my app. The weird thing is: on some views it works on some it doesn't. In my case I have a `.sheet`, and inside of it a Picker.

Comment: I've faced the same issue, it seems like a bug in SwiftUI when ```pickerStyle(.wheel)```. When I use ```pickerStyle(.segmented)``` or ```pickerStyle(.menu)```, the same code works as expected. As a workaround, I switched to UIPickerView from UIKit in UIViewRepresentable

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error and I found solution for me:

1. `.animation(.easeInOut, value: showingPicker)`
2. 

```
ZStack {
        Color.black.opacity(0.2)
             .ignoresSafeArea()
       View() // your content here
        if shouldShowPicker {
            assetsPicker(selection: $viewModel.selection,
                   pickerModel: viewModel.pickerModel)
        }
    }.animation(.easeInOut, value: shouldShowPicker)
```

Picker should hide with animation otherwise will be crash. And I don't know why, but `Color.black.opacity(0.2).ignoresSafeArea()` makes it animation smoothly.

Comment: Yes this is still an issue. Thanks for pointing it out,

Comment: Thats incredible, why is that? It crashes also when I add another animation too, it crashes again. I didn't need the Color